# Why this $G$ is non empty?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, gradient-flows

Consider the following gradient system on a doubly connected planar domain $\Omega$:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}&= - u_x;\\ 
\frac{dy}{dt}&= - u_y,
\end{cases}$$
where $u$ is the first eigenfunction of Dirichlet laplacian. i.e. if $\Gamma_0,\Gamma_1$ are respectively inner and outer boundary of $\Omega$, $u$ satisfies the following:
$$\begin{cases}-\Delta u=\lambda_1 u & \text{ in }\Omega, \\
u=0 & \text{ on }\partial \Omega=\Gamma_0\cup\Gamma_1;\end{cases}$$
where $\lambda_1$ is the first eigenvalue. Define,
$$G=\{x\in \Omega: \text{the solution curve of the gradient system starting from $x$ touches $\Gamma_0$} \}$$

> Why $G$ is non-empty?

$\textbf{Note:}$ It is well known that $u>0$ inside $\Omega$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\eta}<0$ on $\Gamma_0$.

Comment: What exactly is $\eta$? The outward normal coordinate?  The inward normal coordinate?

Comment: Outward normal vector.